# count number of duplicate image for each image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, hash

I want to count number of duplicate image for each image. Can anyone help me with the code ? Can someone please answer with the code itself as I'm new to python? Also please fix the logic in the below code as its not appending the correct images in the list

```
unique=[]
duplicate=[]
for i in image_path_list:
    image2 = cv2.imread(i)
    image2 = cv2.resize(image2,(360,480))
    for j in image_path_list:
        if i!=j:
            image1=cv2.imread(j)
            image1=cv2.resize(image1, (360,480))
            difference = cv2.subtract(image1, image2)

            result = not np.any(difference) #if difference is all zeros it will return False

            if result is True:
                duplicate.append(j)
            else:
                unique.append(j)
```

Comment: Relevant: [SO:comparing-two-opencv-images-2d-numpy-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770698/comparing-two-opencv-images-2d-numpy-arrays)

Comment: Use numpy.array_equal(image1, image2)

Comment: How do you define `duplicate image`: All the same? Nearly the same? or Rotated and scaled same? Or something else?